# Is it possible to run Windows 8 (dev preview) in a qemu?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-8-preview

I can't seem to get Win8 up and running in a VM built on Ubuntu with VirtualManager. Is there something about it that prevents running as a guest? It gets as far as the screen below:

[image]

and then it's just:
[image]

**Edit:**
  I'm running a core i7 2630M, with 2G of mem and 1/2 processors allocated (tried both). XP works fine on the exact same VM configuration.

Comment: How about some hardware specs? VT? Have you confirmed qemu provides the requirements to host Win 8?  Have you tried anything in attempts to get it working?

Comment: You can definitely run `win8` guest in `kvm`. I can confirm that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you pass the CPU type to qemu to get VT-x.  Once I did that it worked just fine.

```
/usr/bin/qemu-kvm -S -M pc-0.13 -cpu core2duo,+lahf_lm,+sse4.1,+xtpr,+cx16,+tm2,+est,+vmx,+ds_cpl,+pbe,+tm,+ht,+ss,+acpi,+ds ....
```

If you use **virt-manager**, click on advanced prefs -> Processor -> Configuration -> Copy host CPU configuration -> Apply.  Restart your VM and with some luck, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Win8 requires VT-x. See [this](http://techblog.ginktage.com/2011/09/how-to-install-windows-8-on-virtual-box/) article for getting it working on VirtualBox, for example.

Comment: The i7 2630QM has VT-x; the only two V techs not on that chip are the Vt-d (directed I/O) and Trusted Execution.